# Can't get IPv6 setup statically using CentOS6 on a 1and1 dedicated server

Tags: networking, centos, ipv6, dedicated-server, 1and1

I have a server at 1and1 that I'm trying to setup with a set of static IPv6 addresses. I can't get it to work and have tried every forum and guide I could find on google. Their tech support has told me that the gateway is fe80::1. The IPv6 addresses I'm trying to use have been provisioned using the 1and1 control panel and are assigned to my account. IPv4 networking is setup and working fine, I just need help with IPv6.

Here's the relevant configuration files:

## cat /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
NOZEROCONF=true
GATEWAY=10.255.255.1
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
IPV6FORWARDING=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_AUTOTUNNEL=no
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
```

## cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=""
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MACADDR=""
MTU=1500
IPADDR=74.208.218.179
NETWORK=74.208.218.179
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
BROADCAST=74.208.218.179
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2607:F1C0:812:7d10::/56
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2607:F1C0:812:7d10::1/56 2607:F1C0:812:7d10::2/56 2607:F1C0:812:7d11::/56"
IPV6FORWARDING=yes
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
```

I've setup forwarding for both IPv4 and IPv6 in the kernel via sysctl:

## cat /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
kernel.shmmax=68719476736
kernel.msgmax=65536
kernel.msgmnb=65536
kernel.sysrq=0
kernel.shmall=4294967296
kernel.core_uses_pid=1
```

---

Here's the output of some commands:

## ifconfig

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:27:2B:1D
        inet addr:74.208.218.179  Bcast:74.208.218.179  Mask:255.255.255.255
        inet6 addr: 2607:f1c0:812:7d11::/56 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: 2607:f1c0:812:7d10::/56 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: 2607:f1c0:812:7d10::1/56 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: 2607:f1c0:812:7d10::2/56 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: fe80::219:99ff:fe27:2b1d/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:542041826 errors:158 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:158
        TX packets:517716410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:55707235613 (51.8 GiB)  TX bytes:441496177225 (411.1 GiB)
        Interrupt:19 Base address:0xc000

eth0:0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:27:2B:1D
        inet addr:74.208.109.145  Bcast:74.208.109.145  Mask:255.255.255.255
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        Interrupt:19 Base address:0xc000

eth0:1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:27:2B:1D
        inet addr:74.208.125.133  Bcast:74.208.125.133  Mask:255.255.255.255
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        Interrupt:19 Base address:0xc000

eth0:2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:27:2B:1D
        inet addr:74.208.113.67  Bcast:74.208.113.67  Mask:255.255.255.255
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        Interrupt:19 Base address:0xc000

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
        RX packets:2943936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:2943936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:2949514917 (2.7 GiB)  TX bytes:2949514917 (2.7 GiB)
```

## route -n -A inet6

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                     Next Hop    Flags   Metric  Ref Use Iface
2607:f1c0:812:7d10::/56         ::          U       256     0   0   eth0
fe80::/64                       ::          U       256     0   0   eth0
::/0                            fe80::1     UG      1       45  0   eth0
::1/128                         ::          U       0       0   1   lo
2607:f1c0:812:7d10::/128        ::          U       0       12  1   lo
2607:f1c0:812:7d10::1/128       ::          U       0       0   1   lo
2607:f1c0:812:7d10::2/128       ::          U       0       0   1   lo
2607:f1c0:812:7d11::/128        ::          U       0       2   1   lo
fe80::/128                      ::          U       0       0   1   lo
fe80::219:99ff:fe27:2b1d/128    ::          U       0       9   1   lo
ff00::/8                        ::          U       256     0   0   eth0
```

---

Using this setup, I can ping the default gateway but not anything outside of the 1and1 network:

## ping6 fe80::1 -I eth0

```
64 bytes from fe80::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.442 ms
64 bytes from fe80::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.447 ms
64 bytes from fe80::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.450 ms
^C
```

## ping6 ipv6.google.com

```
PING ipv6.google.com(ord08s12-in-x14.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6052ms
```

Traceroute6 gives the following output:

## traceroute6 ipv6.google.com

```
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2607:f8b0:4009:806::1014), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  ae-1.gw-prtr-r5-2a.slr.lxa.oneandone.net (2607:f1c0:0:10::66:a)  0.819 ms  0.944 ms  1.073 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Is the problem that the gateway is fe80::1 and my ipv6 addresses are 2607:f1c0:812:...? I did have trouble getting the IPv4 setup working since my IPs (74.208.*.*) were on a different subnet than the gateway (10.255.255.1).

---

*Side Note:* If it helps anyone else out there on a 1and1 server, for IPv4, you'll need to modify /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 like so:

## cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0

```
ADDRESS0=10.255.255.1
GATEWAY0=""
NETMASK0=255.255.255.255
ADDRESS1=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY1=10.255.255.1
NETMASK1=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I would expect to see the default gateway on your own network.  Did the provider tell you that `fe80::1` should be your default gateway?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes. I had emailed 1and1 Tech Support and was told the default gateways were IPv4=10.255.255.1 and IPv6=fe80::1. Both gateways were not on the same network, but IPv4 is the only one I can get working.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: Please do not put the word "Solved" in the title. Mark your answer as accepted when the option is available to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup was correct. For anyone else out there with a 1and1 dedicated server, the only way I could get any traffic through is to completely deactivate the 1and1 IPv6 firewall via their control panel. Modifying the rules did not make a difference.